# Determining a pattern of lines in Python

Tags: python, text

I'm new to Python and having trouble thinking about this problem Pythonically. I have a text file of SMS messages. There are multi-line statements I'd like to capture.

```
import fileinput

parsed = {}

for linenum, line in enumerate(fileinput.input()):
### Process the input data ###
    try:
        parsed[linenum] = line
    except (KeyError, TypeError, ValueError):
        value = None
###############################################
### Now have dict with value: "data" pairing ##
### for every text message in the archive #####
###############################################
for item in parsed:
    sent_or_rcvd = parsed[item][:4]
    if sent_or_rcvd != "rcvd" and sent_or_rcvd != "sent" and sent_or_rcvd != '--\n':
        ###########################################
        ### Know we have a second or third line ###
        ###########################################
```

But here's where I hit a wall. I'm not sure what's the best way to contain the strings I get here. I'd love some expert input. Using Python 2.7.3 but glad to move to 3.

Goal: have a human-readable file full of three-line quotes from these SMS.

Example text:

```
12425234123|2011-03-19 11:03:44|words words words words
12425234123|2011-03-19 11:04:27|words words words words
12425234123|2011-03-19 11:05:04|words words words words
12482904328|2011-03-19 11:13:31|words words words words
--
12482904328|2011-03-19 15:50:48|More bolder than flow
More cumbersome than pleasure;
Goodbye rocky dump 
--
```

(Yes, before you ask, that's a haiku about poo. I'm trying to capture them from the last 5 years of texting my best friend.)

Ideally resulting in something like:

> Haipu 3
>   2011-03-19
>   More bolder than flow
>   More cumbersome than pleasure;
>   Goodbye rocky dump

Comment: it would be helfpul if you gave example of input and expected output

Comment: Can you give us a simple example of an input file, and what you expect as an output ? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time

data = """12425234123|2011-03-19 11:03:44|words words words words
12425234123|2011-03-19 11:04:27|words words words words
12425234123|2011-03-19 11:05:04|words words words words
12482904328|2011-03-19 11:13:31|words words words words
--
12482904328|2011-03-19 15:50:48|More bolder than flow
More cumbersome than pleasure;
Goodbye rocky dump """.splitlines()

def get_haikus(lines):
    haiku = None
    for line in lines:
        try:
            ID, timestamp, txt = line.split('|')
            t = time.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            ID = int(ID)
            if haiku and len(haiku[1]) ==3:
                yield haiku
            haiku = (timestamp, [txt])
        except ValueError: # happens on error with split(), time or int conversion
            haiku[1].append(line)
    else:
        yield haiku

# now get_haikus() returns tuple (timestamp, [lines])
for haiku in get_haikus(data):
    timestamp, text = haiku
    date = timestamp.split()[0]
    text = '\n'.join(text)
    print """{d}\n{txt}""".format(d=date, txt=text)
```

Comment: Fantastic! That did the trick. I'm researching the calls you make to understand what exactly is happening here. I see the `line.split` makes parsing easily accomplished. Thanks again.

Comment: One catch: upon importing files using `open` I error at the `except` statement with `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`. Any recommendation for better error handling or parsing here? What'd I miss?

Comment: Got it! Wasn't handling the random blank lines at all. Added to `if haiku` a `and not None`.

Comment: `if not haiku: continue` would be sufficient, as `None` is a falsy value. This is also good place to check for other condition, e.g. lines that are just boilerplate and should not be appended to line your output.

Answer (score 1):

A good start might be something like the following.  I'm reading data from a file named *data2* but the `read_messages` generator will consume lines from any iterable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def read_messages(file_input):
    message = []
    for line in file_input:
        line = line.strip()
        if line[:4].lower() in ('rcvd', 'sent', '--'):
            if message:
                yield message
                message = []
        else:
            message.append(line)
    if message:
        yield message


with open('data2') as file_input:
    for msg in read_messages(file_input):
        print msg
```

This expects input to look something like the following:

```
sent
message sent away
it has multiple lines
--
rcvd
message received
rcvd
message sent away
it has multiple lines
```